# Get the abstract from the contents of documents from a table

Tags: php

I have table that consist of some columns, one of them are `document_content` column (contents of journals) with the text type. I want to parse the contents to get the abstract. I assume that abstract is the content between the words `abstract` itself and `introduction`.

here's my code :

```
$id = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT document_id, document_content FROM tbdocument WHERE document_id IN (' . implode(",", $id) . ')') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $files[$row['document_id']] = $row['document_content'];
}
foreach ($files as $doc_id => $file){
   if (strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT')){
        if (strpos ($file, 'INTRODUCTION')){
            $between  = substr($file, (strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT')+8), (strpos($file, 'INTRODUCTION')-13) - strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT'));
   if (strpos($file, 'Introduction')){
            $between  = substr($file, (strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT')+8), (strpos($file, 'Introduction')-13) - strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT'));
   }
   }
   else {
        if (strpos($file, 'Abstract')){
            if (strpos ($file, 'Introduction')){
                $between  = substr($file, (strpos($file, 'Abstract')+8), (strpos($file, 'Introduction')-13) - strpos($file, 'Abstract'));
            }
            if (strpos($file, 'INTRODUCTION')){
                $between  = substr($file, (strpos($file, 'Abstract')+8), (strpos($file, 'INTRODUCTION')-13) - strpos($file, 'Abstract'));
            }
        }
    }   
    $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_metadata SET document_id = {$doc_id}, metadata_abstract = '{$between}'") or die(mysql_error());

}
```

but it gives me blank result. what's wrong with my code? thank you very much :)

Comment: First, you can significantly simplify your logic by using `stripos` (case-insensitive) instead of `strpos`: http://us2.php.net/stripos

Comment: Next, you might consider a regex solution, which could be either in SQL or PHP.

Comment: @ctrahey oh, thank you ! I will try to use `stripos`

Answer (score 0):

Besides some simplification of your logic, you're missing a bracket in your `foreach` loop (it should look like this):

```
foreach ($files as $doc_id => $file){
   if (strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT')){
        if (strpos ($file, 'INTRODUCTION')){
            $between  = substr($file, (strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT')+8), (strpos($file, 'INTRODUCTION')-13) - strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT'));
        }
        if (strpos($file, 'Introduction')){
            $between  = substr($file, (strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT')+8), (strpos($file, 'Introduction')-13) - strpos($file, 'ABSTRACT'));
        }
   }
   else {
        if (strpos($file, 'Abstract')){
            if (strpos ($file, 'Introduction')){
                $between  = substr($file, (strpos($file, 'Abstract')+8), (strpos($file, 'Introduction')-13) - strpos($file, 'Abstract'));
            }
            if (strpos($file, 'INTRODUCTION')){
                $between  = substr($file, (strpos($file, 'Abstract')+8), (strpos($file, 'INTRODUCTION')-13) - strpos($file, 'Abstract'));
            }
        }
    }   
    $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_metadata SET document_id = {$doc_id}, metadata_abstract = '{$between}'") or die(mysql_error());

}
```

EDIT: another problem might be that there could be situations where $between is never defined?  What if `(strpos($file, 'Introduction')-13) - strpos($file, 'Abstract')` returns a non-positive value? Then the text would be truncated or not returned at all.

Comment: I've added it, but it still does not work. fyi, I can use this code to parse from txt files, but when I try to use this code (with a little change) to parse content of a table, it does not work.

Comment: @rosen_ Can you comment out parts and tell us which section is going wrong?  I assume your SQL `SELECT` statement's working?  How about the `$between` assignment?  Let us know where we should be looking.

Comment: yes, the SQL `SELECT` statement's working well. I confused with `$between` assigment. when I try to print the `$between` it prints nothing. but the code does not return the error, it just blank result.

Comment: @rosen_ trace your if statements - are you sure the code is even getting to a line where `$between` is assigned?  There are plenty of ways that it might not get there.  What if `(strpos($file, 'Introduction')-13) - strpos($file, 'Abstract')` returns a non-positive value?  Then the text would be truncated or not returned at all.